# SVN replace branch with another - NO merge

Tags: linux, svn

in my project I have configuration files separately in SVN. The needs to stay on the server, so I have an SVN checkout job that run before any deploy.
If I want to deploy on my server a previous version how can I overwrite all the configuration files without having merge problem? (e.g. version 2.3 is currently on server, I need to deploy version 2.2 with a patch, and consequently update all the configuration files at version 2.2)

Basicly I want to replace an entire branch with another, avoiding any conflict.
I can use rm -rf (unix server), but is a bit risky.

Comment: you can checkout particular version also using `svn -r`

Comment: Alternatively you can use SVN -> switch -> another branch

Comment: Cool, I like SVN switch! Is there a way to avoid any conflict with that? this job should be executed automatically on the server without any problem or user interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SVN switch using this command - `svn switch branch-2.3 branch-2.2`
For this you need to have these per-equites -

1. Branch should be cleaned up, no .svn temp files should come in picture
2. Any of the local changes may go away.! So make sure that, you have everything committed.

So you can handle these things easily using commands and perform the job.! Hope this help.